# Finding the first occurrence per index in Multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe called panel_long looking something like that:

```
                 x  y  z event Start
company period   
A       1        1  2  3 False 5
B       1        1  2  3 False 7
...
A       27       1  2  3 True  5
B       27       1  2  3 False 7
...
A       31       1  2  3 False 5
B       31       1  2  3 True  7
```

As a preparation for a survival analysis with [livelines](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quickstart.html) I'd like to add a column which states the first Period event equals True per company. For non-multiindex dataframes I'd use idxmax, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work for a multiindex df. Among others, I've tried the following:

```
def funct(df, column):
    df[column].idxmax()

df = panel_long.groupby('company').apply(funct, ('event'))
```

But that just returns an empty dataframe. Any ideas? I'm stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `return` the output in your self-define function

```
def funct(df, column):
    return df[column].idxmax()
df.groupby('company').apply(funct, ('event'))
Out[248]: 
company
A    (A, 1)
B    (B, 1)
dtype: object
```

Comment: What I don't understand is why the output has (A, 1) instead of 1 in the column. Why is that the case and how can I solve that?

Comment: @TiTo look at your index ,that is Multiple index , when we pull out the idxmax this will return both index. for the mean time , do df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('company').apply(funct, ('event'))